# background перекрывает содержимое

Tags: css, background, position

Нужно позиционировать `h1` абсолютно, чтобы всегда было по центру при изменении масштаба. Высота задана `100vh`. Но вот когда `h1` создаю, он находится за перекрытием `.overlay`. Как его правильно в данном случае позиционировать, чтобы он всегда был по центру и никакие блоки его не перекрывали? `z-index` не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#first {
  background: url(../img/header.png) no-repeat center top /cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  height: 77px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(79, 134, 157, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79, 134, 157, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(79, 134, 157, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79, 134, 157, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79, 134, 157, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79, 134, 157, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(79, 134, 157, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4f869d', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=1);
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main_menu_list_item a {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

.main_menu_list_item {
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main_menu_list_item:hover {
  background: #375f73;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.phone {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.heading h1 {
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.2rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.heading p {
  font-size: 51px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section id="first">
  <header id="header">
    <nav id="navbar">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-4 col-sm-3">
            <div>
              <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Логотип">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7 d-none d-lg-block">
            <ul class="main_menu_list d-flex justify-content-center">
              <li class="main_menu_list_item">
                <a href="#">Главная</a>
              </li>
              <li class="main_menu_list_item">
                <a href="#">О компании</a>
              </li>
              <li class="main_menu_list_item">
                <a href="#">Недвижимость и переезд</a>
              </li>
              <li class="main_menu_list_item">
                <a href="#">Контакты</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 d-lg-flex col-sm-6 col-md-5 ml-auto d-sm-flex d-none align-items-center">
            <div class="icon">
              <img src="img/phone.png" alt="icon">
            </div>
            <div class="phone">
              +7 (495) 12-321-345<br> +7 (495) 12-321-345
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Болгария</h1>
    <p>ждет вас</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Или я слепой или я не наблюдаю тега `h1`

Comment: `z-index` - не будет работать, если элементу не задано правило `position`

Comment: Элементу `.overlay` задано `position`, а у `h1` нет...  У всех элементов по умолчанию `z-index:auto;` А в твоем случае выходит, что `auto` у `.overlay` `z-index:auto;` имеет больший приоритет

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ сделай, галочку поставлю

Comment: Благодарю, Сам ответ напиши, галочку поставь, а я  плюсану...  Я просто занят...